# how to loop datagridview full rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using foreach loop to check data in each row from my datagridview and I want to avoid the headline and the empty buttom line, how do I do that?
that's my simple loop:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string datatocheck = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    if (datatocheck == "done")
    {
        row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop instead.

Comment: `if (!row.IsNewRow) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Using the iterator in a for loop you can easily skip the first and last rows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    string datatocheck = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    if (datatocheck == "done")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

So starting 'i' at 1 rather than 0 skips the first row, and making sure that 'i' is always less than the total number of rows minus 1 skips the last row.

Comment: when I change from foreach - loop to for - loop, the 'row' isn't recognize

Comment: yep I changed it as well, thanks for fixing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ you can do next

```
var doneRows = dataGridView1.Rows
                            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Skip(1)
                            .Where(row => row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals("done"));

foreach (var row in doneRows)
{
    row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Or seems you working only with `DataGridViewCell`

```
var doneCells = dataGridView1.Rows
                             .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                             .Skip(1)
                             .Select(row => row.Cells[2])
                             .Where(cell => cell.Value.ToString().Equals("done"));

foreach (var cell in doneCells)
{
    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```